# VTK 7.0.0 ImageTracerWidget hidden behind imageactor

Tags: python, vtk

Using python, I am trying to draw an ROI around an image. For testing, I have the following code. But, the glyphs hide behind the image. I also don't see the ROI being drawn when I lower the transparency of the overlain image:

```
import vtk


imageSource = vtk.vtkImageCanvasSource2D()

imageSource.SetScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
imageSource.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(3);
imageSource.SetExtent(0, 20, 0, 50, 0, 0);
imageSource.SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
imageSource.FillBox(0, 20, 0, 50);
imageSource.SetDrawColor(255, 0, 0);
imageSource.FillBox(0, 10, 0, 30);
imageSource.Update();

actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(imageSource.GetOutputPort())
actor.VisibilityOn()
actor.AddPosition(10,10,-13)
actor.InterpolateOff()

ip = vtk.vtkImageProperty()
ip.SetColorWindow(2000)
ip.SetColorLevel(1000)
ip.SetAmbient(0.0)
ip.SetDiffuse(1.0)
ip.SetOpacity(1.0)
ip.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()

actor.SetProperty(ip)


renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()

renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.ResetCamera()


renderWindow= vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleImage()
interactor.SetInteractorStyle(style)



tracer = vtk.vtkImageTracerWidget()

tracer.SetInteractor(interactor)
tracer.SetViewProp(actor)
tracer.AutoCloseOn()

renderWindow.Render()
tracer.On()

vtk.vtkMapper.SetResolveCoincidentTopologyToPolygonOffset()  
vtk.vtkMapper.SetResolveCoincidentTopologyPolygonOffsetParameters(10,10)


interactor.Start()
```

At a loss here. I hope someone experience can bail me out of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas the issue seems to be a bug in the last VTK-7.0.0. I reverted my setup to VTK-6.1.0 and the issue is resolved. Now the VTKImageTracerWidget draws just fine

Answer (score 0):

I found it was fixed in VTK8.0  "it was modifying the lines without calling Modified on them"

more detail:
"https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/commit/35e42be7eb61ed5d0dbea6db468776080e900443#diff-4374799689b56389f1a2c2f6fc250110